# Only first datetimepicker works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

Only the first form's datetimepicker works properly.  All the subsequent ones do not allow the user to select a different date (i.e. button doesn't change and value not changed in text field) or the user to change the month, although the time sliders work fine in all cases.  Any help as to why this may be failing would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Modal with datetimepicker as one field in the form:

```
<div id="edit_time_modal_<%= order.id %>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit_order_modal_label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel"><%= order.name %></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body pt0 pb10">
    <%= form_tag update_order_time_url(order_id: order.id), method: "patch", remote: true do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :order_start_date_time, order.order_start_date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), class: "edit-order-datetime", placeholder: "Start date & time" %>
...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= button_tag '<i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Update Order'.html_safe, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.edit-order-datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss', showSecond: false, stepMinute: 15 });
</script>
```

Where the modal is rendered and called from:

```
<tbody id="dashboard_orders_table">
  <% @todays_orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr id="dashboard_order_row_<%= order.id %>">
      <td><a href="#edit_time_modal_<%= order.id %>" role="button" class="modalbutton" data-toggle="modal"><%= order.order_start_date_time.strftime("%l:%M") %></a></td>
      <%= render 'edit_time', order: order %>
...
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So there are multiple modals containing a date field, not multiple date fields within this one form / modal. Correct?

Comment: There are multiple rows of "orders" in a table, each order has its own modal and form to update the datetime of the order but only the first one in the table works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have more than one label with the id `myModalLabel` if you have more than one order/edit_time partial. Change that to a class and see if the selectors resolve the events on subsequent inputs.

Also make sure each form has a unique `id` set.

Comment: $(function() {
  $('#edit_order_datetime_<%= order.id %>').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss', showSecond: false, stepMinute: 15 });
  });

Answer (score 0):

A few things for troubleshooting:

1. Make sure all the date fields are using the same `edit-order-datetime` class.
2. Make sure all modals are loaded in the DOM before the JavaScript executes. Try using jQuery's [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Like this:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $('.edit-order-datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss', showSecond: false, stepMinute: 15 });
   });
   ```

If the modals are rendered on the fly though (i.e. when row is clicked) rather than when the DOM is first loaded, you will need to call the $.datepicker each time a modal is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I gave each form and datetime input its own unique id and inserted ruby into the js to call datetimepicker on each unique datetime input:
    $(function() {
      $('#edit_order_datetime_<%= order.id %>').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss', showSecond: false, stepMinute: 15 });
      });

```
<%= form_tag update_order_time_url(order_id: order.id), method: "patch", remote: true, id: "edit_time_#{order.id}" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :order_start_date_time, order.order_start_date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), class: "edit-order-datetime", id: "edit_order_datetime_#{order.id}", placeholder: "Start date & time" %>
...
<% end %>
```